# How do I configure maven to run certain ANT commands

Tags: maven-2, maven

I use the maven-antrun-plugin (which are bound to a certain phase) to run ANT tasks. How should I run a certain task manually (e.g. something like mvn start-jboss) which is not bound to a maven lifecycle phase.

Comment: To me, regarding the plugin documentation, it doesn't seem like this is possible. What's the problem with using a lifecyle phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mvn antrun:run

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html

you can also set parameter in the for a non default task in the project's pom.xml